# Undo last command possible?

Tags: shell, command-line

In windows you can undo an operation if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. E.g. you delete a file in the gui then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and the file will be restored and appears in the folder again.

Is there something similar in linux but with commands?! E.g. i accidentially unzipped a file, and i want to undo the operation (all files should dissapear again).

Comment: You can't undo all commands on Windows, only some GUI ones.  These are usually file managers (if they've sent to the recycle bin) or other applications.  Utilities which carry out system tasks don't accept Ctl-Z.  It's a similar situation on Linux, some applications (such as word processors) will accept it, but utilities won't.  I can't imagine how you could undo a disk format in either systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short answer is no. There is no "undo command" on GNU/Linux terminals.

Although lots of commands have an inverse operation, like rename, compress, decompress, etc.